# get two BLE device with onScanResult in android

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I tried to get two device name and address inside onScanResult function in Android but I couldn't get these information. As I understand this function call peridicly itself until stop searching and the function give some result about the founded device but I couldn't get how many device found and device information at the same time.

Here is my code :

```
private ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {

        if("MyBLEdevice".equals(result.getDevice().getName())){
            bleDevice = result.getDevice();
            if(bleScanner !=null){
                bleScanner.stopScan(scanCallback);
            }

        }

        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
    }
};
```

I change my code but I couldn't stop scanResult

```
boolean isDuplicate = false;
private ScanCallback scanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {

        if("MyBLEdevice".equals(result.getDevice().getName())){

            for(BluetoothDevice device : mLeDevices)
            {
                if(device.getAddress().equals(result.getDevice().getAddress())){
                    isDuplicate = true;
                }
                if(!isDuplicate){
                    mLeDevices.add(result.getDevice());
                }
                if(mLeDevices.size()==2)
                {
                    bleScanner.stopScan(scanCallback);
                    bleScanner.flushPendingScanResults(scanCallback);
                }

            }

        }

        super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
    }
};
```

Comment: `I also tried to ArrayList but it also not work for me.` show how you tried

Comment: private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> mLeDevices;
……
mLeDevices.add(result.getDevice());

Comment: looks not bad. What was wrong with it?

Comment: Size always return 1

Comment: Because of this I need to create Arraylist outside of the onScanResult but I couldn find where is the correct place

Comment: as a field of the class

Answer (score 2):

You continuously get results, each result is for one device only, from scan even for the same device as soon as new advertisement is send.

To get list with unique devices you should remove duplicates and better choice is to update the device that is already on the list when you receive update for that device.

You can get the 2 specific devices by using `device.getName()`, make sure that you are advertising names, long names are not send via advertisement, or Service UUIDs by

```
List<ParcelUuid> parcelUuids = result.getScanRecord().getServiceUuids();
```

and compare this UUID you created to advertise.

Comment: Device name and services are the same. Because of this I tried to filter device with address. Is it possible to filter address with List?

Comment: MAC Addresses for devices other than beacons are virtual. MAC address change when you restart the adversing app so trying to filter devices via [MAC address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36180407/why-the-address-of-my-bluetoothdevice-changes-every-time-i-relaunch-the-app) won't work. You should either filter with device name or advertising UUID, check with an app from Play Store if you are advertising correctly, i use nRF Connect app it's quite good.

Comment: But the device name and services are the same.