# android 6.0: search for devices via bluetooth

Tags: search, bluetooth, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am developing a Bluetooth application. First at all I Need to search available Bluetooth (bt) devices. This works for android 4.3 up to 5. ... 
but not on the new Version android 6. When I press the button "search for devices" the bt-receiver starts but finds no device. What interesting Thing could that be? Do I Need other permissions than for older Versions of android?

I can't give you the code, because it is my companies app. But I would be really appreciated if you know sth. about this difficulties and give me some evidences.

Thank you!

Comment: I found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052811/since-marshmallow-update-bluetooth-discovery-using-bluetoothadapter-getdefaultad for guys with the same problem